# Why does Python2.7 insist on Python3 print statement?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, nose, nosetests

I was trying to see how nose & unittesting were being used in a package I'm learning about. This package uses nosetester, which is provided with numpy (why this is done also confuses me). My nosetester.py is in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/. I am running Python 2.7.6. However, when I add a tracing statement of the form:

```
print "Hi"
```

to the __init__ method of the NoseTester class, I get a syntax error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/nosetester.py", line 182
print "Hi"
         ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I use

```
print ("Hi")
```

things work fine. I know my Python interpreter is using 2.7.6:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

This leaves me wondering why the insistence on Python3 and is there anywhere else that I might run into this?

Comment: Is there a `from __future__ import print_function` line in nosetester.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `nosetester.py` has a line like

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

This makes the Python2-style print statement `print "foo"` unavailable and requires you to use the Python3-style print function `print("foo")` instead.